# Text file as datasource to display data in gridview

Tags: c#, .net

Text file data looks like below:

FacilityID:12787 FacilityName:ACME Medical Center FacilityLocation:XYZ

FacilityID:27875 FacilityName:Medical Center FacilityLocation:kh

```
private void ReadFile(string fileName)
        {               
            var rows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
            Char[] separator = new Char[] { ':' };
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable(fileName);
            if (rows.Length != 0)
            {
                foreach (string headerCol in rows[0].Split(separator[0]))
                {
                    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headerCol));
                }
                if (rows.Length > 1)
                {
                    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < rows.Length; rowIndex++)
                    {
                        var newRow = tbl.NewRow();
                        var cols = rows[rowIndex].Split(separator);
                        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols.Length; colIndex++)
                        {
                            newRow[colIndex] = cols[colIndex];
                        }
                        tbl.Rows.Add(newRow);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**To add data in datatable written above code.
but it is not filling properly.**
**"Datatable Wrongly Filled"**

```
FacilityID:12787 
FacilityName:ACME Medical Center 
FacilityLocation:XYZ
FacilityID:27875 
FacilityName:Medical Center 
FacilityLocation:kh
```

***How should i modify the code the datatable should be filled like below***

```
 FacilityID  FacilityName        FacilityLocation
    12787    ACME Medical Center XYZ
    27875    Medical Center      kh
```

Comment: What is the question? (Minus for spell errors and no question so far)

Comment: Artyom: Please check i have updated quetion..My quetion is read data from text file and show it onto gridview

Comment: Don't understand the question. So do it. What's the problem?

Comment: Is there some exception? What does "Datatable Wrongly Filled" mean?

Comment: i need data to be displayed row wise FacilityID,FacilityName etc are coloumns

Answer (score 0):

Some stuff which is already available on net may be helpful to you
please go through these links:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ReadTextFile.aspx
http://aspalliance.com/1107_CodeSnip_Reading_CSV_Files_Using_Dataset.all
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/ConnectODBCText11262005070206AM/ConnectODBCText.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
   private string GetID(string str)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str.Split(':')[1]))
        {
            return str.Split(':')[1].Replace("FacilityName", string.Empty);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    private string GetName(string str)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str.Split(':')[2]))
        {
            return str.Split(':')[2].Replace("FacilityLocation", string.Empty);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    private string GetLocation(string str)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str.Split(':')[3]))
        {
            return str.Split(':')[3];
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }


    private string Button Click()
    {
        string rows = "FacilityID:12787 FacilityName:ACME Medical Center FacilityLocation:XYZ";
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable("test");
        if (rows.Length != 0)
        {
            tbl.Columns.Add("FacilityID");
            tbl.Columns.Add("FacilityName");
            tbl.Columns.Add("FacilityLocation");
            var newRow = tbl.NewRow();
            newRow[0] = GetID(rows);
            newRow[1] = GetName(rows);
            newRow[2] = GetLocation(rows);
            tbl.Rows.Add(newRow);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tbl.DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A little explanation of your code wouldn't hurt anyone.

Comment: In my sample i am using string. but you can change like read from file. Column Names is constant, not changed you can use this above one. ":" split ok. But problem after split you get actual value + next column name. so here i remove the column name from cell value.